# use concat function postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I want to run this code but got this error

> HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

```
execute $$SELECT MAX(date) FROM $$||table_name INTO datum;
IF datum is not NULL THEN

      execute $$DELETE FROM $$||table_name||$$ WHERE date >= $$||quote_literal(datum);
ELSE
      datum := $$2001-01-01$$;
end if;
execute $$
INSERT INTO $$||table_name||$$
(number, date, departement, minutes)
 select
     number, gs.date,
```

where (beg, enddate) overlaps (concat($$||quote_literal(datum)||$$, '00:00:00'), concat($$||quote_literal(datum)||$$, '23:59:59'))

Let's notice also that **where (beg, enddate) overlaps (concat($$||quote_literal(datum)||$$, '00:00:00'), concat($$||quote_literal(datum)||$$, '23:59:59'))** want to do it only when datum != $$2001-01-01$$; (not for the first iteration).

Thank you,

Comment: `||` is enough.

Comment: what do you mean please.? @ceving

Comment: `||` is already a concatenation operator, which concatenates. So, you won't need to use concat additionally. Read more here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-string.html

Comment: What data type is `datum`?

Comment: i see i did this before **$$||quote_literal(datum)||$$ '00:00:00'** and got error also:::::::: psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near ""00:00:00""

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name date

Answer (score 1):

When using dynamic SQL, it's better to use `format()` to construct the SQL and use placeholders for parameters so that you don't need to cast values back and forth:

```
execute format('SELECT MAX(date) FROM %I', table_name) 
   INTO datum;

IF datum is not NULL THEN
      execute format('DELETE FROM %I WHERE date >= $1', table_name)
          using datum;
ELSE
   datum := date '2001-01-01'; 
end if;

execute format('
INSERT INTO %I
(number, date, departement, minutes)
select
     number, gs.date,
      (case
            when trim(string) ~ '^ADM[0-9]$'
              or TRIM(string) ~ '^ADM[0-9]$'
       then 'ADMINISTRATION'
      end) as departement,
sum(extract(epoch from (least(s.enddate, gs.date + interval '1 day' -
                           greatest(s.beg, gs.date)
                          )
              ) / 60) as minutes
from smp s 
  cross join lateral generate_series(date_trunc('day', s.beg), date_trunc('day', least(s.enddate, current_date)), interval '1 day') gs(date)
where (beg, enddate) overlaps ($1 + time '00:00:00', $1 + time '23:59:59'))', table_name)
using datum; -- pass the parameter as a proper date
```

Comment: thank you but im gotting error saying that **psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "datum" does not exist** Notice that datum is a variable not a column. @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: @biwia: well your query uses a column `datum` and you told me the data type of that column is `date`. I can only use the information you provide. Or did you mean to reference the `date` column from `generate_series()`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_name  sorry its my fault I created like this. Sorry i was not clear **execute $$SELECT MIN(sign_in_date) FROM $$||table_name INTO datum;**

Comment: So that's part of a larger PL/pgSQL function? Then please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64046955/edit) your question and show us the complete function. The whole query doesn't really make sense to me to begin with. And why the `$$` quoting around the `select` that makes no sense either

Comment: thank you, post edited. Please have a look @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Thank you so much @a_horse_with_no_name when using your method, how can i say to the program you execute the **where clause ** only when datum != date '2001-01-01' (not in the first iteration). Hope that im clear. Thank youuu

Comment: @biwia: something like `and $1 <> date '2001-01-01'`

Comment: in that case it will never do it . Because to initialize my value to '2001-01-01'. Tell me if im not clear. Am i wrong .?

Comment: @biwia: you should ask a new question for that.